# How can I get labels with mediaDevices.enumerateDevices

Tags: android, cordova, webrtc, ionic4, mediadevices

I'm listing the devices of my phone in a ionic 4 app using Angular7 and  cordova. Calling `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` I got all *audioinput* and *videoinput* but the label is empty. 
I know I have to call to this method when the audio and video permissions are granted and I do that.

Connecting to a webrtc sample through Android browser works but through Android WebView not.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  I am having the same issue running in a Cordova app

Comment: No solution or workaround found ...

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late but, in case someone else needs it: I found that, at the moment, there is no solution because it is not an Ionic or Capacitor bug.

Rather, it's because of the way WebRTC is handled internally by the WebView.
I found the solution [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/3022#issuecomment-651741218):

> WebRTC is handled internally by the WebView, not by Capacitor,
> Capacitor only requests the required permissions, so this is a bug in
> the WebView and we can't fix it.
>
> You can report it to google, but I've found this old issue that they
> closed as won't fix
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=669492